# Get number of overlapping characters in PHP or MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, string-comparison

I want to calculate the number of overlapping characters in a comparison with two strings. Suppose you have these comparisons:

```
       boel <-> baal
       boel <-> bol
beestenboel <-> boelsten
beestenboel <-> baastenb
      hallo <-> hello
```

The results must be like these:

```
BoeL         } b matches, o does not match,
BaaL         } e does not match, l matches.
               Result: overlap = 2

BOeL         } b matches, o matches, l matches
BO L         } e does not match (it's not present in the lower string).
               Result: overlap = 3

B EeSTENboel } b matches, e matches (because o is only present in the lower
BoElSTEN     } string), the second e is no longer present (since we have
               already consumed an e from the lower string, l does not match,
               s, t, e, n match successively.
               (Notice that b, e, o and l from the upper string will be ignored,
               since all characters from the lower string have already been
               consumed.)
               Result: overlap = 6

BeeSTENBoel  } b matches, the two e's do not match with the two a's, and again,
BaaSTENB     } s, t, e, n match.
               Result: overlap = 6

HaLLO        } h matches, a doesn't match
HeLLO        } l, l and o match.
               Result: overlap = 4
```

I suspect I'm thinking too complicated... How can I achieve above results in MySQL or PHP?

(I guess the levenshtein algorithm is related to this question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This description reminds me of all the DNA aligning algorithms I learned during my studies. I'm not exactly sure, that you need all of the stuff they are doing, but have a look at [Needleman-Wunsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) and [Smith-Waterman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith-Waterman_algorithm).

Comment: I finally solved the question using the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm. It first calculates the alignment between both strings using a score scheme, which is a scheme to assign penalty points to substitution, insertion or deletion per character from the second string. Since I only need to know whether characters match with both strings, the penalty remains the same (usually 0), leaving only scoring points to matching characters. I found a document which perfectly explains the algorithm: http://www.mcemperor.nl/downloads/pub/Needleman-Wunsch%20algorithm%20Melbourne%20Bioinformatics.pdf. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned yourself, the [levenshtein](http://php.net/levenshtein) algorithm is probaly what you need, so i'd suggest you to try that out. Whether it will return exactly the results you are expecting im unsure of, but you should look into all the comments on the page. There is so much gold to be harvested in the [comment section](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php#106381)

If you have root access to your server, you can also [install this on your mySQL server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/udf-compiling.html#c8098), thanks to Matthieu Aubry

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that will work for you: http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), but since your column is in English and assuming that it is one word length, you can use [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) it can be applied to get the matching strings see [this](http://databases.about.com/od/development/l/aasoundex.htm) :

```
SELECT
  Word,
  SOUNDEX(Word) AS SoundTest,
  DIFFERENCE(Word, 'textentered') As DiffTest
FROM
  YourTable
```